Hint IDE with column names (and types) of a pandas dataframe
Assume you have a pandas dataframe df that has the column foo. Then, in Jupyter when you type df.fo<TAB> the column name will be completed.
This works when df is in memory.
However, if df is not in memory then you can't TAB complete the column name.
Is there a way to TAB complete the column name in an IDE when df is not in memory?
More specifically, assume that I develop a function. I can give type hint to df so when inside the function I can get completions related to pandas.
import pandas as pd
def my_function(foo: pd.DataFrame, bar: pd.DataFrame):
    foo.joi<TAB>

Here, foo.join will be completed and in general I can see the available methods for foo.
My question is, what about the columns of the dataframe (and their types)? Is there a way to get completions for the columns of the dataframe when df is not in memory? I have in mind something like type hinting that hints the IDE about the columns of the dataframe.
Similarly, to how you can hint a dictionary with Dict[str, Dict[int: str]] and then you get completions for the keys of the dictionary.
A bonus question is, how can this be done with PySpark dataframes?

Not sure in Jupyter Notebook, but this facility is available in an IDE (like Visual Studio Code).

@Mr.Hobo I'm not sure what you mean... How can I hint VScode to know what's the expected types of columns in a dataframe? Or what are the columns if it has not been initialized.

@Dorr use some linters like "pylint" or "python" for VS Code.
